# (Ag-Grid) While editing, how to get value changed immediately, not after cell loses focus?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In ag-grid, while entering some values in table, I need to receive updated values on `input` or `change` event.

But `onCellValueChanged` is triggered only when cell loses focus, and I cannot figure out what is the way to get values immediately.
The only restriction I have - I can't add custom cellEditor, it needs to be grid default.

Can someone, please, advise how to reach such behavior?

Comment: Mila, "receive and updated" means "receive and update" or "receive an updated"? Fix please this. Also you can highlight keywords by StackOverflow markup, like adding "`" around 'change' and other scripty-keywords.

Comment: Was anyone able to solve this problem? I have the same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current value of the cell whilst editing by leveraging the Grid Event `onCellKeyDown`:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/keyboard-navigation/#keyboard-events

```
var gridOptions = {
    onCellKeyDown: params => {
        console.log('current value', params.event.target.value)
    },
}
```

Please see this sample which showcases this: https://plnkr.co/edit/GbMglD1fxTTeSZFj

Answer (score 2):

According to [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/) you can use a custom callback `onCellEditingStopped`.

This will trigger every time a cell editing is ended.

You define it directly on the grid options object and you can also access the edited values (and its row and column) like this:

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [/* whatever */],
  defaultColDef: {/* whatever */},
  rowData: rowData,
  onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.oldValue); // cell's previous value
    console.log(event.newValue); // cell's new value
    console.log(event.column); // the column that was edited
    console.log(event.data); // the row that was edited
  },
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

[Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/#stop--end-editing) you have a detailed explanation of whenever this `onCellEditingStopped` is triggered.

You can also inspect the [full example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/#example-cell-editing).

Comment: Unfortunately this event seems to fire fairly late - only when the cell's focus is lost